# Samsung washer trips breaker during spin

Tags: circuit-breaker, washer

I appreciate any help. I have a 5.6cf Samsung washer. Model WF56H9100ag/a2. It pops the circuit breaker mid spin cycle. It’s only 4 years old and has not moved. I have opened up everything except the drum and everything is clean and dry. the water exit filter is clean. 
I put it into service mode and run the quick spin test and it failed at about 850rpm and 1050rpm. 
There is no slip in the bearings. (I had a kenmore elite that failed that way so I’m familiar with the signs) 
The motor is clean and spin fine.

Only other issue and I’m not sure if it’s normal, the drum shakes a lot during spin startup. Then it spins smoothly. Not sure if that is a signal.

Thank you!![image]

Comment: I don’t think so. It’s just the mains breaker panel

Comment: Yes it does and it trips the breaker when pressed.

Comment: @Justind can you get us photos of the breaker that's tripping?

Comment: #22 is dedicated washer

Comment: Can you try running the spin diagnostic until the breaker trips, and when you go to reset the breaker, hold TEST down while resetting the handle, then timing the amount of time it takes the breaker to trip again?

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question...I tripped it, held test and reset it. Did you want me to run the spin test again and let you know how long it takes to trip again?

Comment: Is it a bkr with a white test button arc fault or purple dual function breaker.? Knowing you have a variable speed drive in the machine it would not surprise me if it is the breaker.

Comment: Ty. It’s breaker 22 in the pic above.

Comment: @EdBeal -- it's a dual function breaker (purple button)

Comment: With all the focus on breakers, where I was focused on washer, I plugged it into another circuit and it passes the Quick Soin test!!  Thank you all for the help. MUCH appreciated!

Comment: @Justind -- that is *very* bizarre.  Is that other outlet also protected by a Dual Function breaker?

Comment: I’ll have to track it since it’s just in the hallway. Is a dual function needed or can I replace with single function?

Comment: I have seen a large number of these breakers fail (not only square D but all mfg’s) with variable speed drives and electronic dimmers. Oregon has an exemption for devices that are known to have trouble with AFCI’s in code versions prior to the 2020 code I hope they keep it for things like this.

Comment: @Justind -- plug it into a kitchen outlet (use a heavy-duty extension cord if need be, since this is a temporary test setup)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I plugged it into a GFIC in the bathroom and it passed the spin test!!  Picking up a new breaker for the box. 

Cheers all. You saved me a lot of time and headaches!!

Answer (score 1):

Hallways have typically AFCI protection to protect from fires in the wiring in the walls.

Laundry rooms must have GFCI protection to protect humans from being electrocuted by faulty appliances.

It's likely the laundry room also has AFCI protection, since circuits that need GFCI can also have fires from wiring in the walls. So from the purple button, we know that is a dual-mode AFCI+GFCI.

So by moving the washer from the laundry room to the hallway, you removed GFCI protection.

And the problem went away!

Well, no, actually, your **ability to detect the problem** went away.   Problem is still there.

A GFCI problem means that the appliance is leaking electricity internally due to failing insulation or perhaps a bad capacitor.  If it wasn't for ground, it would be giving you a nasty shock (> 5 ma).  It's repairable.